# CSS: Insert a Newline After a Text Character

Tags: html, css, insert, newline

How can I insert a newline after the first period in this code using only CSS?

```
<footer>©2004-2015 Delta Systems, Inc. All Rights Reserved.</footer>
```

I know that to insert a newline after an element it's like this:

```
h4 { display: inline; float: none; }
h4:after { content: "\a"; white-space: pre; }
```

But is it possible to do it after selecting a specific character?

Comment: Could you force the text to wrap onto a new line by reducing its width instead?

Comment: There is a no 'element' as such in your `footer` (based in the supplied HTML) just raw text...that means you can't really select it at all with CSS. Other than that...no. CSS styles content..it can't detect it.

Comment: be cool if we had some sort of :nth-word() psuedo! but no there isn't. As @grc says you could  always force it to use a new line by setting width.

Comment: No... CSS can't read! :P

Answer (score 0):

You could try playing with word-wrap and width like so.

HTML:

```
<footer>©2004-2015 Delta Systems, Inc. All Rights Reserved.</footer>
```

CSS:

```
footer {
   width: 220px;
   word-wrap: break-word
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwypPY